# Line Spacing react-draft-wysiwyg

Tags: draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg, line-height

I want to implement Line Spacing options (single,double, exactly ,line per inch) in react-draft-wysiwyg editor but currently i don't think that it is support [Custom line spacing](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/issues/173) , [Open Issue  ,](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/issues/214) problem statement is i want to apply different line spacing on different paragraphs as per user input how i should be able to implement this feature ?

By changing line height of editor it will apply line height on whole editor but i want to be specific on user selected paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set `blockData` and in render via `blockstylefn` set the correct style to block.
Take a look at these:

- https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/248#issuecomment-335010079
- https://gist.github.com/joshdover/7c5e61ed68cc5552dc8a25463e357960.